# How do i keep my content not moving from inside the grid after i add more stuff, for example an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so im doing a Rock, Paper, Scissors game so i can play with javaScript and Jquery but im having trouble with the css.

Where i added the paragraph i want to add an image, depending on what the user chooses in the select box. I added a paragraph just to test it, im gonna add the image once i get my css fixed lol.

I want the 1st grid to look exactly like the 3th grid, which doesnt have anything above it yet.

Oh and also i have another question, this is my first time using Jquery, but i tried doing an alert and its not working, am i doing it right?

My code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

```css
body{
 background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
 background-color: #F7B05B;
}

#titulo{
 background-color:#FCDE9C;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
 margin-left:80px;
 margin-right:80px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap:10px;
  grid-template-columns: 450px 360px 450px; /* 3 columnas */
  grid-template-rows: 450px;  /* una sola fila */
  margin:30px;
}

#usuario{
  grid-column-start: 1; /* es lo mismo que grid-column: 2/3; */
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

#computadora{
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

#resultado{
  border-color: #C7EF00;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #F3DFA2;
}

.texto{ /* This is what i want inside my grid but it keeps going lower when i add something*/
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 250px;
 position:relative;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 font-size:25px;
}

.estilo{
  border-color: #F7CE5B;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-color: #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.botones{
 padding:20px;
 font-size:25px;
 font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
 font-style:bold;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background-color: #2D3142;
 border:none; 
 color: #FCDEBE;
}

#nuevoIntento{
 padding: 20px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
 font-style:bold;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background-color: #561D25;
 border-color: #ECDD7B; 
 color: #FCDEBE;
 width:250px;
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 7px;
 margin-top:25px;
}

#imageHolder{
 /* This is the place where i want to insert an image, in this case i added a paragraph to test my css */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="javascript1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai|Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Piedra, Papel o Tijera</title> 
</head>

<body>
 <header id="titulo">
 <h1>PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA!</h1>
 </header>
 <div class="grid-container">

  <div id="usuario" class="estilo">
   <div id="imageHolder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam cumque, aspernatur explicabo? Hic, officiis ad minima, tenetur atque alias beatae cum optio libero amet, commodi, quaerat iste consequuntur sint placeat!</p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="texto">
    <h3>Seleccione una opción:</h3>
    <select id="seleccion" class="botones">
     <option value="Piedra">PIEDRA</option>
     <option value="Papel">PAPEL</option>
     <option value="Tijera">TIJERA</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="resultado">
   <div class="texto">
    <p>Aca va mi resultado</p>
    <button id="nuevoIntento" onClick="window.location.reload();">Volver a intentar!</button>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="computadora" class="estilo">
   <div class="texto">
    <h3>Haga click y espere resultado:</h3>
    <button class="botones"> Click me!</button>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost doing the alert right. Ironically creating an alert is actually by using the word `alert`. This is Vanilla (non-jQuery or other library) JavaScript and is supported by every browser.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
});
```

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Still not working, i think im messing up the link of the jquery

Comment: Place your own script **after** the jQuery script. Very important!

Comment: do you mean write my code on the same html page using <script> tags? But i want to write my javascript on an external text, that's im linking the js too :/

Comment: In the example above you first `javascript1.js` and then `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`. But the browser works from **top** to **bottom**. So if you use jQuery in `javascript1.js` it will not be there because it is loaded on the next line of your HTML. Switch those two lines and you'll be fine.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you! i cant believe it was just that, im so angry LMAO

Comment: No worries, mate. It has happened to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is just overflowing out of the bottom of your container. your `margin-top` on `.texto` is set to `250px`, which is too high. Just set that to a lower number and it will display correctly. If instead you want the entire box to stretch to fit it's content, you'll need to remove the line `grid-template-rows: 450px;`, as it is defining how tall a row can be.

```css
body{
 background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
 background-color: #F7B05B;
}

#titulo{
 background-color:#FCDE9C;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
 margin-left:80px;
 margin-right:80px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap:10px;
  grid-template-columns: 450px 360px 450px; /* 3 columnas */
  margin:30px;
}

#usuario{
  grid-column-start: 1; /* es lo mismo que grid-column: 2/3; */
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

#computadora{
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

#resultado{
  border-color: #C7EF00;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #F3DFA2;
}

.texto{ /* This is what i want inside my grid but it keeps going lower when i add something*/
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 250px;
 position:relative;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 font-size:25px;
}

.estilo{
  border-color: #F7CE5B;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-color: #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.botones{
 padding:20px;
 font-size:25px;
 font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
 font-style:bold;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background-color: #2D3142;
 border:none; 
 color: #FCDEBE;
}

#nuevoIntento{
 padding: 20px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
 font-style:bold;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background-color: #561D25;
 border-color: #ECDD7B; 
 color: #FCDEBE;
 width:250px;
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 7px;
 margin-top:25px;
}

#imageHolder{
 /* This is the place where i want to insert an image, in this case i added a paragraph to test my css */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="javascript1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai|Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Piedra, Papel o Tijera</title> 
</head>

<body>
 <header id="titulo">
 <h1>PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA!</h1>
 </header>
 <div class="grid-container">

  <div id="usuario" class="estilo">
   <div id="imageHolder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam cumque, aspernatur explicabo? Hic, officiis ad minima, tenetur atque alias beatae cum optio libero amet, commodi, quaerat iste consequuntur sint placeat!</p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="texto">
    <h3>Seleccione una opción:</h3>
    <select id="seleccion" class="botones">
     <option value="Piedra">PIEDRA</option>
     <option value="Papel">PAPEL</option>
     <option value="Tijera">TIJERA</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="resultado">
   <div class="texto">
    <p>Aca va mi resultado</p>
    <button id="nuevoIntento" onClick="window.location.reload();">Volver a intentar!</button>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="computadora" class="estilo">
   <div class="texto">
    <h3>Haga click y espere resultado:</h3>
    <button class="botones"> Click me!</button>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```